# Add custom attributes to a Tk widget

Tags: python, tkinter

My main target is to add something like an hidden tag or string to a widget, to save short information on it.
I got the idea of creating a new custom Button class (in this case I need buttons), which inherits all the old options.

This is the code:

```
form tkinter import *

class NButton(Button):
    def __init__(self, master, tag=None, *args, **kwargs):
        Button.__init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs)
        self.master, self.tag = master, tag
```

No trouble when creating a new NButton instance:

```
aria1 = NButton(treewindow, bd=2, relief=GROOVE, text="Trasmissione\naerea 1", bg="#99c4ff", tag="aria 1")
aria1.place(x=20, y=20)
```

The problems come out when I try to get the value of `tag`:

```
aria1["tag"]
```

it returns:

> _tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-tag"

How can I solve this?

Comment: While subclassing can be used to add custom attributes to `Tk` widgets, it's not necessary to explicitly assign the `master` attribute to `self`. It's already done by`Button.__init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to access your custom options as object attributes:

```
print(aria1.tag)
```

Comment: Is there another option for adding user-defined attributes instead of subclassing?

Comment: @Wolf: yes. `b = tk.Button(...); b.something="something"`.

Comment: I see, thanks a lot. Sometimes it's so easy that it's too hard to expect for a C++ programmer ;)